# c# passing in paramater into another method

Tags: c#, parameters, charts, delegates, zip

I am trying to define a helper class which is used to plot graphs, I was told to use Zip method to pass in each element of the array X and Y into another method, but it didn't work out nicely, can any expert point out what I have done wrong? I couldn't find any similar circumstances using Google.

Or is it just me being too imaginative, this way couldn't work out at all?
I have see examples of calculating a pairs of x , y points using Zip method, but not passing in as parameters.

Situation : My program has a 2 functions and 1 delegate, the first function called PlotXYAppend is used to invoke the delegate PlotXYDelegate which then passed in the method Points.addXY to do the plotting, the reason why I used chart.Invoke here is for thread safety reason .

But the problem I had is the delegate or plotxyappend only take a pairs of points at a time,so  I came up with a method , which is to create another function called PlotXYPass to pass in the a pair of XY points into plotxyappend to get it working, but i think there is some problem i can't solve, the intelisense is telling me they don't like the parameter i put in this function.

I greatly appreciate for any help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;


namespace LastTrial
{
    public class PlotHelper
    {
        double[] X = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        double[] Y = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };


        Chart chart;// declare chart as chart type
        Series dataSeries;// declare dataSeries as Series type



        private delegate int PlotXYDelegate(double x, double y);

        private void PlotXYAppend(Chart chart, Series dataSeries, double x, double y)
        {
            chart.Invoke(new PlotXYDelegate(dataSeries.Points.AddXY), new Object[] { x, y });
        }// this line invokes a Delegate which pass in the addXY method defined in Points, so that it can plot a new point on a chart.


        private void PlotXYPass(double[] X, double[] Y)
        {
            X.Zip(Y, (x, y) => this.PlotXYAppend(chart,dataSeries,x,y));
        }

// trying to pass in x,y points by extracting pairs of points from list []X and []Y into the function above which only takes a pair of x,y points
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private object PlotXYAppend (Chart chart, Series dataSeries, double x, double y)
{
    return chart.Invoke(new PlotXYDelegate(dataSeries.Points.AddXY), new Object[] { x, y });    
}

public IEnumerable<object> PlotXYPass (double[] X, double[] Y)
{
    return X.Zip<double, double, object>(Y, (x, y) => this.PlotXYAppend(this.chart, this.dataSeries, x, y));
}
```

Then remove the laziness upon call, like:

```
var ph = new PlotHelper();
ph.chart = this.chart;
ph.dataSeries = this.chart.Series[0];
var result = ph.PlotXYPass(ph.X, ph.Y).ToList();
```